# Role of memory segmentation in modern architectures

Tags: assembly, memory-segmentation

As we know that these days , we have multi-processor architectures available such as dual core , core i3, i5, which may have many gigs of RAM. My question is that ia memory protection through segmentation still available in these modern architectures.

(keeping in mind , in earlier architectures such as iAPX 88, we could get benefited from segmented memory modal which would allow us to open 64 K window for every segment ds,es,ss,cs)?

How much size of window will open in 3 GB RAM For these segment registers cs,es ,cs,ss, in case of modern architectures?